# Getting ClassNotFoundException on running a Jenkins job via Git

Tags: git, jenkins

I am running getting class not found error if I run my project in Jenkins via Git.

The project is working fine if I change it to local workspace from Git.

I am trying to execute the program using mvn exec:java.

Following is the executable maven plugin config:

```
 <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>Tests</mainClass>
                    <arguments>
                        <argument>arg0</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Where "Tests" is the executable class.

Error is below:

> [WARNING]  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: main.java.Tests
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass (URLClassLoader.java:471)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:588)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:521)
>       at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run (ExecJavaMojo.java:270)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:834)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was resolved by using

```
mvn install exec:java
```

instead of

```
mvn exec:java
```